# How can a vector field eat a smooth function?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields

I was watching this Frederic Schuller's lecture on [Grassmann algebra and de Rham cohomology](https://youtu.be/QLnzIOGIvfo). I don't understand. At 43:40 it looks like a vector field is eating a smooth function.

The $X_i$ should be a vector field, that is a section of a smooth tangent bundle. So it should map a point on the manifold to one of the point's tangent vectors. But omega is a $0$-$n$ tensor field, that is, a function that takes n vector fields and outputs a smooth function (manifold $\to \mathbb R$). So how can you give the $X_i$ a smooth function when it should eat a point of the manifold? What am I missing?

Comment: $X(f)$ at $p$ is the result of tangent vector $X_p$ acting on function $f$ at $p$, I suspect he covers this in an earlier lecture

Comment: @CalvinKhor Is this just notation, like, lets call X(f), where X is a vector field and f is a smooth function, the function defined by p in M is mapped to X(p)(f)? Or is it true that the functions X that takes a smooth function and outputs a smooth function taking p to X(f)(p) are isomorphic to the functions X that takes a point on the manifold and map it to a tangent vector?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative

Comment: @p.h.f. it's the first case. I don't know if there is a sense in which they are isomorphic.

Comment: The X(f)(p) in my comment should be X(p)(f).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2860143/what-exactly-is-frac-partial-partial-xi-bigg-p @CalvinKhor, here's the sense in which they're isomorphic. You view the usual direction derivative $D_v$ as an operator which is also a derivation. Observe that $D_{e^j} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}:= \partial^j$ i.e $D: \{e^1,...,e^n\} \mapsto \{\partial^1,...,\partial^n\}$. This is the isomorphism, hence vectors are just derivations.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood I'm aware of the isomorphism between the 'geometric tangent vectors' and 'derivations', but I feel like the maps $f\mapsto \mathcal L_X f $ and $p\mapsto X_p $ are very different

Comment: They are. All I gave was an identity $\mathcal{L}_Xf (p) = X_p(f)$.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood Oh, I understand what you mean now.

Answer (score 1):

Given $\vec{v} = (v^1,...,v^n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f: \mathbb{E}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. Then  we define $\vec{v}[f] = \sum_j \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j} v^j$. Given a vector field $X: U \to \mathbb{R}^n$  we have $X_p \in \mathbb{R}^n_p$. We can choose a basis $e^1_p,...,e^n_p$ at $\mathbb{R}^n_p$ such that,

$$X_p = \sum_i a(i,p) \ e^i_p$$

- We then identify $X_p$ with its coordinate form i.e $(a(1,p),...,a(n,p)) \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then we let $X[f]$ be the vector field such that,

$$ X[f] (p) := X_p[f] = \sum_j \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j}  \cdot a(j,p)$$

- Here we write $[f]$ to be the germ class of $f$. The germ class of a smooth function $f$ at $p$ are all the other smooth functions which agree with $f$ on a neighborhood of $p$. Recall that such functions have the same directional derivative.
- The whole reason behind all this is that it can be shown that derivations at $p$ are isomorphic to the tangent space at a point, which are just vectors. To see this full carried out, see **Loring Tu's** *"Introduction to Manifolds"*.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this in Schuller's lecture on [Differential Structure](https://youtu.be/UPGoXBfm6Js?t=2540) during the aside on derivations and algebras.

Recall that a tangent vector $X_{\gamma,p}\in T_pM$ is nothing but a derivation $D:C^\infty(M)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $X_{\gamma,p}\mapsto X_{\gamma,p}f = (f\circ \gamma)'(0)$.

When you apply $X\in \Gamma(TM)$ to a smooth function on $M$, you obtain a real number for each $p\in M$, i.e. a smooth function on $M$. So a vector *field* on $M$ is nothing but a derivation $D:C^\infty(M)\rightarrow C^\infty(M)$ defined exactly as in the comments: $X\mapsto Xf$ where $(Xf)(p) = X(p)f=X_{\gamma,p}f$ for all $p\in M$.